# How to use postman to send request to this script

Tags: php, json, postman

I have this scripts and I need to use postman to send request. But I do not know how to implement it in this script, the documentation is here https://bongolive.co.tz/api/docs but I didn't get the clear descriptions from it because I am a beginner

```
<?php
//.... replace <api_key> and <secrete_key> with the valid keys obtained from the platform, under profile>authentication information
$api_key='<api_key>';
$secret_key = '<secret_key>';
// The data to send to the API
$postData = array(
    'source_addr' => 'INFO',
    'encoding'=>0,
    'schedule_time' => '',
    'message' => 'Hello World',
    'recipients' => [array('recipient_id' => '1','dest_addr'=>'255700000001'),array('recipient_id' => '2','dest_addr'=>'255700000011')]
);
//.... Api url
$Url ='https://sms.bongolive.africa/api/v1/send';

// Setup cURL
$ch = curl_init($Url);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization:Basic ' . base64_encode("$api_key:$secret_key"),
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postData)
));

// Send the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Check for errors
if($response === FALSE){
        echo $response;

    die(curl_error($ch));
}
var_dump($response);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not really getting the question. What is it you need Postman for and what is the issue with your code? Does it work? Do you get errors? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I build a example step by step for you, notice the key words which are `quoted`.

The sample reference to official api document

`https://bongolive.co.tz/api/docs/`

about `Sample request data`.

---

#### 1. Create a new tab

#### 2. Set api `Url` with `https://sms.bongolive.africa/api/v1/send`

[image: URL]

#### 3. Change `Method` to `POST`

[image: Method]

#### 4. Set `Authorization` to `Basic Auth`

The green block are variables in `{{` and `}}` refer to your `api_key` and `secret_key`

[image: Authorization]

#### 5. `Header` Set `Content-Type` to `application-json`

(it may be changed if BODY's raw type changed)
and you can see that your header of `authorization` is here too

[image: Header]

#### 6. Add `Body` raws data

with `JSON` format

[image: Body]